# Spreadsheetgear tick mark position

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, charts, spreadsheetgear

I'm using spreadsheetgear 2012 to create Excel charts in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Can someone please help me figure out how to reposition the tick marks so they sit directly over the top of the tick label?
In Excel, you'd do this by clicking Format Axis, Axis Options, then select "On tick marks" under "Position Axis", but I can't find the function to call in spreadsheetgear to do the same thing.
At the moment, all charts created with spreadsheetgear position the tick label between two tick marks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IAxis.[AxisBetweenCategories](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IAxis~AxisBetweenCategories.html) property to false would correspond to choosing "On tick marks" from Excel’s "Format Options" panel.  Example:

```
chart.Axes[AxisType.Category].AxisBetweenCategories = false;
```